# Why does http PATCH reset double properties to 0 with jpa/spring mvc?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-boot

When I do an http PATCH to this model to update the "bar" value it works as expected.

```
@Entity
@Table(name='Foo')
class Foo {
    @Id
    String id = UUID.randomUUID()    
    double bar
    String baz
}
```

If instead, I do a PATCH to that same endpoint but ONLY include baz (leaving bar out of the payload completely) the database and returned JSON show the bar value was set to 0

Does anyone know why a PATCH would update the double value without it being in the body?

I'm using the default stack that ships w/ spring-boot 1.1.6 at this time (including data-jpa/ security/ web)

Comment: Can we assume you are using Spring Data REST? Otherwise the statement "When I do an http PATCH to this model" wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: Correct- sorry I assumed the spring-boot reference would make this more clear (but yes - Spring Data REST is in the mix -> I have no controller defined)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do a PATCH then the following happens:

- An new instance of `Foo` is created
- `Foo` is populated with all values that have been sent with the request
- The `Foo` entity with the id provided by the URI is loaded
- All properties that differ between the two objects are copied from the new `Foo` to the persisted `Foo`, unless the value is `null` in the new `Foo`.

As you have seen that rather simple algorithm is extremely problematic when it comes to primitive values or any default values. `bar` will always be `0` in a new `Foo` instance and will therefore be copied if the persisted value is not `0`. The problem is much bigger then one might think. Imagine `baz` had a default value, like `""`.

Your answer already contains one possible workaround for primitives, but unfortunately you can't cover default values in general. IMHO it's a serious bug caused by laziness.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who might follow it appears you need to use the capital **Double** instead of the lowercase double

```
@Entity
@Table(name='Foo')
class Foo {
    @Id
    String id = UUID.randomUUID()    
    Double bar
    String baz
}
```

Comment: you mean a Double _Object_, rather than a double primitive (and you have semicolons missing). Presumably for Java bean requirements?

Comment: Could be bean/dep injection related (not sure at the time I'm writing this). I realized hibernate/jpa would default to zero for the primitive and not for the Double object (the end result I was hoping for originally. Also Double is nullable vs the primitive double)